# unable to execute karate script in Firefox webdriver docker container

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, firefox, ui-automation, karate

I tried to execute the karate script using webdriver docker containers -  selenium/node-chrome-debug:latest and selenium/node-firefox-debug:latest. I could able to  execute the karate script in chrome container but not in firefox container .

Its throwing - http response code: 500 "Reached error page: about:neterror?e=connectionFailure" , although proxy is set , its not loading any page instead displays unable to connect error page in firefox  . I have latest version 1.1.0 in pom.

Below are the docker commands executed :

docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --net network --name selenium-hub selenium/hub:latest

docker run -d  -p 5900:5900 --net network -e HUB_HOST=selenium-hub -e -NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=1 -e NODE_MAX_SESSION=1 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/node-f network -e HUB_HOST=selenium-hub -e -NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=1 -e NODE_MAX_SESSION=1 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/node-firefox-debug:latest

Below are the karate driver config tried. But issue exists the same for all the below config

```
karate.configure('driver', { type: 'geckodriver', webDriverSession: { capabilities: { browserName: 'firefox' } , desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'firefox' } } , start: false, showDriverLog: true, webDriverUrl: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub' });


karate.configure('driver', { type: 'geckodriver', start: false, showDriverLog: true, webDriverUrl: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub' });


karate.configure('driver', { type: 'geckodriver', start: false, showDriverLog: true, webDriverSession: { capabilities: { browserName: 'firefox', proxy: { proxyType: 'manual', httpProxy: 'proxyurl' } },desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'firefox' } } , webDriverUrl: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub' });
```

Issue exists the same even with firefox standalone docker container!

Comment: I have no idea. This is not something Karate claims to support, so please contribute code or share any solutions you find.

Comment: HI @PeterThomas , Thanks for your reply ! I see  Karate supports W3C WebDriver and you did mention that it can work with remote grid as well !
I just followed exact same steps mentioned in the webdriverurl and webdriversession . It works fine with chrome container but not for  firefox  as its not loading any page . 
For some reason its not setting up the proxy even though proxy is mentioned in driver config for Firefox container as you can see in  karate.config  but  i could able to validate the proxy if i do printenv . Any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: @PeterThomas - Also if this is an issue then  kindly let me know the steps to follow  to get started with  the code contribution process  ! Thanks

Comment: Any help would be much appreciated **from you** :) here are the code contribution instructions you need: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: @peter - Thanks for sharing the instruction .will look into it and reach out if i need any further details .  Please let me know if we have inbuilt karate-firefox container exists already ? since i saw this somewhere in  discussion regarding karate-firefox docker container but when i tried with docker hub it doesn't exists !

Comment: someone contributed a PR - but it has not been tested: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-docker/karate-firefox - please don't expect any more hand-holding, you have to do some research on your own